# Stack Memory "leak" in C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

Consider the below code segment:

```
void f() {
    int arr[10];
    arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    puts("");
    free(arr);
}
```

Will the original `arr[10]` stack memory be freed when the function f returns? (Or is this a stack memory leak?)

Comment: You can't assign values to array types.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I don't think this code would even compile. Have you tried it?

Comment: You've declared `int arr[10]`.  If you had used `int *arr` then this question would make sense.

Comment: Why don't you just try to compile this and watch the compiler errors? And use correct prototype-style declarators!

Comment: Good point - it didn't compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do

```
 arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
```

like you've done (*tried to do*) in your code snippet. `arr` is array type and assignment is not permitted on that.

Subsequently, maybe worthy to mention, calling `free()` on a non-dynamically allocated pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

FWIW, "leak" comes into picture for the memory allocated by the dynamic memory allocation (generally, heap). For variables allocated in "stack" area (by compiler) need not to managed (for de-allocation or *free* -ing) from your program.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the array arr, you are already assigning space (on your function stack) to it. It doesn't make sense to make the malloc'd memory (which gets allocated on the heap) assigned to that array.You are invoking compile error doing that. You should have used a pointer instead of declaring that array. A pointer will grab and store that malloc'd space for you.

Comment: You do not invoke undefined behavior by assigning `malloc`ed memory to an array. The behavior is well defined: It produces a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

int arr[10]; this array is already allocated from stack;
to allocate array dynamically declare it as a pointer 
int *arr;

dynamic allocation will not be automatically freed, use free or similar to free it;